# How do I exclude tmp files from Samba full_audit?

Tags: server, samba

I'm running a File Server with Samba on Ubuntu Server, and recently the need to log who deletes or modifies files has become quite critical.

In order to do that, I added the following lines to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
vfs objects = full_audit

full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
full_audit:success = mkdir rename unlink rmdir pwrite
full_audit:failure = none
full_audit:facility = local7
full_audit:priority = NOTICE
```

and this on `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
local7.*                        /var/log/samba/log.audit
```

The issue is that we have at all times at least 40 people accessing the fileserver, which results in a giant wall of text with `.tmp` files on the logs.

Is there a way to make `full_audit` exclude the TMP files from the audit?

Answer (score 0):

add this lines. example:

in [global]

```
# full audit
   full_audit:prefix = %I|%m|%S
   full_audit:success = mkdirat read pread write pwrite renameat unlinkat
   full_audit:failure = none
   full_audit:facility = LOCAL5
   full_audit:priority = notice
```

in shared folder:

```
[my_shared_folder]
   # change it to the name of your shared folder
   comment = my_shared_folder
   # change it to the path to your shared folder
   path = /home/your_user/my_shared_folder
   public = yes
   read only = no
   writeable = yes
   browseable = yes
   # change "your_user" to your user (echo $USER)
   valid users = nobody your_user
   force user =
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   available = yes
   printable = no
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   # exclude file extensions
   veto oplock files = /*.tmp/*.doc/*.docx/*.pdf/
   # Include file extensions
   veto files = /*.mp3/*.3gp/*.asd/*.au3/
   vfs object = full_audit recycle
```

source: [samba full audit](https://www.maravento.com/2021/12/samba-full-audit.html)